# Lista iterando millones de elementos con coste O(1) en Python?

Tags: python, visual-studio, lista, bucles

les muestro el experimento que estaba haciendo. La idea era básicamente hacer una comparación de tiempo entre encontrar cierto elemento en una lista Vs. encontrarlo en un arreglo de listas en Python (ya lo había hecho en Java con resultados esperados).
Resulta que creando una lista en Python y creando un método simple para iterar, el tiempo de busqueda (si es que la clase time que importé está bien) es siempre el mismo, busque el elemento 1 o el 10000000.
No le encuentro el sentido a esto porque el método buscarDato itera a través de un for, o sea que debería tardar mucho más tiempo en hallar el resultado si éste es un número grande.
La pregunta es ¿Qué exactamente está pasando? ¿Hay algo acerca de las listas de Python que no sepa?

Gracias de antemano por la respuesta!

```
    
import time
            
class Lista:    
    def buscarDato(self, lista, dato):

        dato = dato

        for i in lista:
            if i == dato:
                print("Encontrado: " + str(dato))
        return dato        


lista = []
    
for i in range (0,1000000):
    lista.append(i)
    
prueba = Lista
dato = 0
    
inicio = time.time()
dato = prueba.buscarDato(lista, lista, 999999)
fin = time.time()
    
print(str(dato) + " encontrado")
print("Tiempo: " + str(fin - inicio))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El detalle es que no estás rompiendo el ciclo dentro de la función `buscarDato` una vez que se consigue el número que buscas. Por ende, siempre que corres el código, se itera sobre todo el millón de elementos completo, obteniendo siempre los mismos resultados en cuanto a tiempo.

Debería ser:

```
for i in lista:
    if i == dato:
        print("Encontrado: " + str(dato))
        return dato
```

---

Ahora bien, y esto ya no es relacionado con la pregunta, el código no está bien escrito. Permíteme apuntar varias cosas que pueden ser corregidas:

1. En primer lugar, es mejor usar `timeit` que `time.time()` para medir el tiempo de ejecución de una función. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/389173/156415) en donde proveí una función que utiliza `timeit.timeit()` para medir tiempo de otras funciones.
2. No tiene sentido hacer una clase si no vas a hacer encapsulamiento o abstracción de ningún tipo de datos ni comportamientos. Usa solo una función y ya.
3. Esta línea: `dato = dato` no tiene ningún sentido. Si quieres asignar valores a un atributo de una clase, hazlo a través de la instancia (`self`) de esa clase que es pasada automáticamente al invocar los métodos de la clase. Sería `self.dato = dato`. (Aunque igual no estarías haciendo nada con esa asignación dado tu ejemplo particular)
4. No estás instanciando la clase `Lista` correctamente. Sería `prueba = Lista()`
5. Esta línea no hace nada: `dato = 0`
6. No estás invocando la función `buscarDato` correctamente. Al hacerlo a través de una instancia de la clase, el primer argumento, como ya mencioné, se pasa automáticamente. La invocación quedaría así: `prueba.buscarDato(lista, 999999)`

Comment: Muchas gracias!